# Eclipse RCP Multiple PresentationReconciler

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am writing my custom editor and need now more than one Scanner. My code is likely the example code from Vogella.

```java
    public class PropertiesReconciler extends PresentationReconciler {

    private final TextAttribute tagAttribute = new TextAttribute(
            Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));

    public PropertiesReconciler() {
        RuleBasedScanner scanner = new RuleBasedScanner();
        IRule rule = new PropertyNameRule(new Token(tagAttribute));
        scanner.setRules(new IRule[] { rule });
        DefaultDamagerRepairer dr = new DefaultDamagerRepairer(scanner);
        this.setDamager(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
        this.setRepairer(dr, IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    }
}
```

```xml
    <extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.genericeditor.presentationReconcilers">
    <presentationReconciler
         class="com.vogella.ide.editor.tasks.PropertiesReconciler"
         contentType="com.vogella.ide.contenttype.tasks">
   </presentationReconciler>
</extension>
```

What I need is a second Scanner similar to the RuleBasedScanner.
So how can I add multiple scanners in the PresentationReconciler?

Comment: Usually you use a PartitionScanner to break up the document into several partitions and set a separate Damager/Repairer for each partition.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used the generic editor so I don't know how these things fit in with that.

Comment: Can I use the TextSourceViewerConfiguration in a GenericViewEditor?